# Twisted canonical commutation relations

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

I am dealing with universal C*-algebra generated by $x,y$ with the following relations: $xy = qyx$, $x^{*}y = qyx^{*}$, $y^{*}x = qxy^{*}$, $x^{*}x = q^2xx^{*} - (1-q^2)yy^{*}$, $y^{*}y = q^2yy^{*} - (1-q^2)$, where q $ \in (0,1)$.
  I need to find (the most simple) faithful representation of it but I couldn’t do it myself and the only reference I found is Pusz, Woronovicz “Twisted second quantization”. In this article I couldn’t understand a thing because it is written kind of with a physics notation.

Does someone by any chance know where else it is written? Or may be give me a hint how to construct it?

Answer (score 4):

Your algebra is a typical example of Wick *-algebra. [Positive representations of general commutation relations allowing Wick ordering (Schmitt, Werner, Jorgensen)](https://arxiv.org/abs/funct-an/9312004) is a good reference for general theory of Wick *-algebras and their (bounded) representations. Example 1.2.3 is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out  how does Fock representation of that work. But haven't you encountered to a faithful representations of TCCR such that generators don't tend to zero as $q$ tends to 1? I am not sure they are even exist...